# IOS (Asyncimageview): Using loadImageWithURl and call backs?

Tags: ios, asyncimageview

Good day all,

Referring to https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

I have gone through their Wiki and examples as well, but i could not find a way to use their API with call backs.

This works fine

```
imageView.imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[singleChannel objectForKey:@"channelimage"]];
```

But i would like to handle image failure. Any snippets on how i can use their "loadImageWithURL" with call backs.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As stated on the main page you can listen for according notifications:

> To detect when the image has finished loading, you can use
>   NSNotificationCenter in conjunction with the AsyncImageLoadDidFinish
>   notification, or you can use KVO (Key-Value Observation) to set up an
>   observer on the UIImageView's image property. When the image has
>   finished loading, the image will be set, and with KVO you can detect
>   this and react accordingly.

There is a notification when the image has finished loading (`AsyncImageLoadDidFinish`) as well as when the image failed being loaded (`AsyncImageLoadDidFail`). So in your case just subscribe your observer for `AsyncImageLoadDidFail` notifications for your image view.

Comment: I was hoping there was some kind of block based interface to this. Is there one?